# How to check if input was highlighted (not focused) and clear on new input in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I have possible strange or noobie question, but I have code that blocks input length on 4 digits

```js
onKeyPress={(e) => {
  if (
    e.target.value.includes(".") &&
    e.target.value.split(".")[1].length >= 2
  ) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, -1);
  }
}}
```

due to this, I have a float number of type like 1.33, 15.99, and so on.

Atm I have a problem, how to clear the field when the user selects all symbols with a mouse and presses for example 1, this 1 will always go to the end of the current input and that is logical. Like this[image] Does anyone have any idea how to track that the symbols were highlighted by a mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this using `onChange` instead of `onKeyPress`. There needs to be one extra change the length check needs to be **3** since the value function will trigger after the input has changed.

Currently in Firefox you can't use `document.getSelection()` on a `input` element, see [MDN getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getSelection#related_objects)

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <input
      onChange={(e) => {
        if (
          e.target.value.includes(".") &&
          e.target.value.split(".")[1].length >= 3
        ) {
          e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, -1);
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```